# setState not working inside useEffect hook and token is showing null everytime

Tags: reactjs

I am building a wrapper which will see if token is present or not in the localstorage then
it will render the component otherwise redirect the user to the login page.
The auth and token state are not getting changed...

```
import Home from "./Home";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Protected_home() {
    const[token , setToken] = useState(null)
    const [auth,setAuth] = useState(false)

    useEffect(()=>{
        setToken(localStorage.getItem("noty__auth__token")) //not working
        console.log("token fetched") // getting a log the token
    },[])

    useEffect(()=>{
        setAuth(true) // setting auth to true
    },[token])

    useEffect(()=>{
        alert(token) // getting null
    },[auth])

    // conditional rendering of the components
    if(auth){
        return <Home/>
    }else{
        return <Redirect to={{pathname:"/"}}/>
    }
}

export default Protected_home
```

Answer (score 0):

you should setItem in localsotorage and then use getItem method if you've done setting the value check your browser storage to see is there any data or not.
check this thing out too

```
 useEffect(()=>{
     const data = localStorage.getItem("noty__auth__token");
     if(data) setToken(data)
    },[])
```

Comment: Setting data in localstorage is getting carried by login component. And the value is present but still it is not working...

Comment: change this 

````const[token , setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem("noty__auth__token")````

Comment: But why? I can also fetch the token during the mounting of the component. What is the difference?

Comment: the difference is initializing the State with localstorage key item, with this you are not gonna take an empty state in the first place

Comment: Ok. But why my approach of taking the token during mounting is not working? What thing I was missing?

Answer (score 0):

Trying giving the conditions before setting state. As on first render every useEffect will be called unlike of dependency array.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("chek");
    const data = localStorage.getItem("noty__auth__token");
    if (data) {
      setToken(data); //not working
      console.log("token fetched");
    } // getting a log the token
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("auth");
    if (token) {
      setAuth(true);
    } // setting auth to true
  }, [token]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("alert");
    //alert(token); // getting null
  }, [auth]);

  // conditional rendering of the components
  if (auth) {
    return <h1>welcomehome</h1>;
  } else {
    return <h2>hey</h2>;
  }

}
```

Comment: I actually figured out that If I removed the redirect component then my logic is working perfectly. What does the redirect component actually doing?